# Visual Studio app deploy is deleting extra files on Azure web site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I'm using the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml Visual Studio 2013 Template for CI builds from visualstudio.com to an Azure website and it's working great.

However, I need to keep additional files on the server (the app creates files). If I was using the "Web deploy" method, I'd simply disable the "Remove additional files at destination" property, but I don't see an option for that using the Azure deployment template.

I should be able to add /p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True to the MSBuild arguments in the build definition, but it isn't working. Files are still being deleted from the web server when I deploy.

I've also tried creating a publish profile and adding it to the template. It hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to keep app-created files while using visual studio deployment. I suggest you to create an Azure Storage account and store those files in the storage (blob would be good enough). It seams that you are using ASP.net. See more detail at [Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn261237.aspx).